# Files could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: angular, gulp, gulp-watch, asp.net-core-1.0

I realize this question has been asked before, but I haven't found an answer that specifically addresses this issue.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on a project with Core 1 (MVC 6), Angular2 and the project is in TFS.  I'm using Gulp-watch to copy html/css/js files over as I work on them and this works *most* of the time. I have most of wwwroot in my .tfignore file including my "app" folder where all those files are being copied/cleaned by gulp and gulp-watch.  I know tfignore settings are working because TFS is not trying to commit those files. However when Gulp does a clean on that folder I get a "could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.".  This TFS check slows down the process when I build and that's enough to want to fix it, but at times the Gulp-Watch process fails because it doesn't have permissions to copy a specific html file.  The gulp-watch copy error is `EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'dashboard.component.html' at Error (native) Process terminated with code 1.` If I clean and then re-run the Gulp copy there are no permission issues. I'm thinking that possibly TFS is playing a part in this problem even though those files are tfignored.

PS. I've read that you can use gulp-plumber to avoid the stops on errors, but I'm trying to figure out what is causing the TFS errors in wwwroot and hopefully as a result fix the frequent file copy errors first.

Gulp code in question:

```
var appDestPath = './wwwroot/app/';

gulp.task('clearAppDestinationFolderHtml',
    function () {
        return gulp.src(appDestPath + '**/*.html')
            .pipe(clean());
    });

gulp.task('clearAppDestinationFolderCss',
    function () {
        return gulp.src(appDestPath + '**/*.css')
            .pipe(clean());
    });

gulp.task('moveHtml', function () {
    gulp.start('clearAppDestinationFolderHtml');
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.html']).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app/'));
});

gulp.task('moveCss', function () {
    gulp.start('clearAppDestinationFolderCss');
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.css']).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', ['moveHtml']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.css', ['moveCss']);
});
```

The cleaning of the destination folder was only added while trying to fix this problem. I'm realizing that the clean is running at the same time as the copy and could cause it's own issues.  I just recently tried this code as well to copy only the specific file changed and ended up with the same error as before `(operation not permitted, open 'wwwroot\app\User\Components\app.component.ts')`:

```
gulp.task('watch2', function () {
    return gulp.watch('./app/**/*', function(obj){
        if( obj.type === 'changed') {
            gulp.src( obj.path, { "base": "./app/"})
            .pipe(gulp.dest(appDestPath));
        }
    })
});
```

Also here is my .tfignore file:

```
wwwroot/app
wwwroot/scripts
wwwroot/libs
wwwroot/_references.js
app/*.js
app/*.js.map
typings
```

Comment: Can you post the `gulp-watch` code? The `operation not permitted` error is because that .html file is read-only and/or under source control.

Comment: @Barryman9000 The originating folder is under source control, but the destination folder is not under source control.

Comment: Oh so that error probably isn't related to TFS. Have you tried setting the clean tasks to finish before trying to move the files? I'm guessing it's somehow trying to clean files that no longer exist. .tfignore only works for local workspace but as long as your destination files aren't in source control I don't think it's causing this error.

Comment: Barryman, that might help.  I think that's the reason it works better when I run the tasks manually.  I'm pretty green with Gulp, do you have a link/suggestion to implement a reliable way to wait for a task to finish before starting another.  As I understood it's a little difficult to accomplish with Gulp 3.x and 4.x will resolve that issue.  As far as .tfignore goes, these files are not in source control, so I wonder why is TFS giving me the `"could not be found in your workspace.."` warnings everytime I clear those files? Even if it isn't the root of the problem it still slows me down.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only moving files to the `/app` directory, they're probably still read-only. Files under TFS source control are read-only. If that's the case, the [gulp-chmod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chmod) plugin can remove that read-only flag.

Also, [gulp-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean) is deprecated in favor of [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del).

As for the dependency, that's not hard to do with gulp 3. You can either use a plugin called [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) (which is a temporary fix until gulp 4 is released) or you can just set a dependency on the task

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    del = require('del'),
    appDestPath = './app/';


gulp.task('clean:html', () => {
    return del([
        appDestPath + '**/*.html'
    ]);
});

gulp.task('clean:css', () => {
    return del([
        appDestPath + '**/*.css'
    ]);
});

gulp.task('moveHtml', ['clean:html'], function () {
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.html'])
        .pipe($.chmod(666))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});

gulp.task('moveCss', ['clean:css'], function () {
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.css'])
        .pipe($.chmod(666))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.html', ['moveHtml']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.css', ['moveCss']);
});
```