# The item 'some path' could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp

I am creating an ASP.Net Core APP in visual studio 2015 (bound to a tfs server).
I have a task in gulp which cleans up a directory (PQRS) & copies some files, (sort of a bundler/minifier).

I have ensured that I have `nuget` config & I have added the foll : key .

```
<add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
```

Also, from some posts, I have added a `.tfignore` file which prevents checking in the directory contents of PQRS to tfs.

I have pointed out the problem to this.

1) My Task starts.

2) My Task Finishes.

3) In the status toolbar I get this line "`Updating Source Control Status`" & Then the above error comes in output window.

My question matches to some extent to this one. 
[Files could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273591/files-could-not-be-found-in-your-workspace-or-you-do-not-have-permission-to-acc)

However, this guy solves his problem by running clean & then re-running. This does not work in my case.

Comment: Are you running a TFS build or just running a gulp task in VS?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I had tried binding the gulp task to Visual Studio build as well as running the gulp task separately. I am not doing anything such as "TFS Build".